# Splitting string having special character, white space and comma

Tags: apex, string

I have string in below format

```
0030k000002HsSaAAK#2009-06-21 00:00:00,0030k000002HpvTAAS#2003-05-08 00:00:00,0030k000002uxiyAAA#2011-06-29 00:00:00,
```

I have to separate out only dates from this like
`2009-06-21`, `2003-05-08` and `2011-06-29` and then I have to do comparison of the dates and find out the latest date.
Can anyone help me in splitting this.

Here's my current code:

```
set<String> dateSet = new set<String>();
String s='0030k000002HsSaAAK#2009-06-21 00:00:00,0030k000002HpvTAAS#2003-05-08 00:00:00,0030k000002uxiyAAA#2011-06-29 00:00:00,';
List<String> splitstr = new List<String>();
splitstr = s.split('[,]{1}[\\s]?');
system.debug('splitstr'+splitstr[0]);
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: set<String> dateSet = new set<String>();
String s='0030k000002HsSaAAK#2009-06-21 00:00:00,0030k000002HpvTAAS#2003-05-08 00:00:00,0030k000002uxiyAAA#2011-06-29 00:00:00,';
List<String> splitstr = new List<String>();
splitstr = s.split('[,]{1}[\\s]?');
system.debug('splitstr'+splitstr[0]);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2})+');
Matcher pm = p.matcher('0030k000002HsSaAAK#2009-06-21 00:00:00,0030k000002HpvTAAS#2003-05-08 00:00:00,0030k000002uxiyAAA#2011-06-29 00:00:00,');

List<String> dates = new List<String>();
if(pm.find()) {
   do{
       dates.add(pm.group());
   }while(pm.find());
}
System.debug(dates);
```

**OUTPUT**

**(2009-06-21, 2003-05-08, 2011-06-29)**

Comment: Thanks mukesh it worked. Do you know how to compare each date retrieved with a particular date and find the minimum gap out of all.

Comment: @wizard try this: [https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/169849/29734](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/169849/29734)

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that the format will always be like this:

```
<id>#<date><space>
```

then you can get the string, use the `split` method from the String class, and then iterate the strings and get the date using the `substring` method, like this:

```
List<String> dates = new List<String>();
Set<String> data = myString.split(' ');
for (String s : data) {
    dates.add(s.substring(20, 30));
}
```

Note that with this example you will need to parse the date if you want to work with the `Date` class, but that can be easily achieved inside the for loop.

Comment: {List<String> dates = new List<String>();
String st='0030k000002HsSaAAK#2009-06-21 00:00:00,0030k000002HpvTAAS#2003-05-08 00:00:00,0030k000002uxiyAAA#2011-06-29 00:00:00,';
Set<String> data = st.split(' ');
for (String s : data) {
    dates.add(s.substring(20, 30));
}
System.debug('dates'+dates);}

Comment: getting error Illegal assignment from List<String> to Set<String> for Set<String> data = st.split(' ');