# Check if two Date Fields are within 60 Days of each other?

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime

I need to validate whether the Last_Activity_c occurred within 90 days of the Anticipated_DUE_DATE__c

I came up with the below formula, but it picks up Last activity Dates that are greater than the 60 days. If Anticipated Due Date is 1/1/18, it needs to pick up activities from 10/1/2017 only.

```
Last_Activity__c - Anticipated_DUE_DATE__c <= 90
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Compare Two Dates in Apex?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/169838/how-to-compare-two-dates-in-apex)

Comment: I don't think it duplicates that as this is formula field rather than apex

Comment: This is confusing -- "picks up Last activity Dates that are greater than the 60 days".  Are you talking about 90 days or 60 days?  Please give an example of a date that is not working.

Comment: We have a custom field called Anticipated Due Date which the client's next event date. The Sales Team is supposed to be calling within 90 days leading to the event. I need to check is their last activity falls within those 90 days, hope this is makes sense and thank you

Answer (score -2):

IF(Last_Activity_c >(Anticipated_DUE_DATE__c.addDays(90)), False, True)

This formula field of return type checkbox will return "True" ,if Last_Activity_c occurred within 90 days of the Anticipated_DUE_DATE__c.

Comment: Thanks Suraj but that didnt work, i keep getting  "Unknown function Anticipated_DUE_DATE__c.addDays. Check spelling." error message .                  
                                                                                             IF(Last_Activity__c >(Anticipated_DUE_DATE__c.addDays(90)), False, True)

Comment: The original poster is not using Apex.